# How to use query to fetch cloudkit data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, cllocation, ckrecord

I am trying to have all the users' locations stored in `cloudkit`, then downloaded by each device. I marked on the code in `storeLocation` where I get the error:

> "Cannot convert value of type '(NSError?, [CKRecord]?)' (aka '(Optional, Optional>)') to expected argument type '(error: NSError?, records: [CKRecord]?) -> Void'"

```
//saves location in cloud kit //currently works well:

var locArray = [CKRecord]()
func storeLocation(location:CLLocation) {
        let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location")
        locationRecord.setObject(location, forKey: "location")
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { (records, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error saving locations: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Locations saved: \(records)")
                loadLocation((error, self.locArray)) //where I get error******
            }
        }
    }

//fetches location from cloud kit:

func loadLocation(completion: (error:NSError?, records:[CKRecord]?) -> Void)
{
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Location", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil){
        (records, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error fetching locations")
            completion(error: error, records: nil)
        } else {
            print("found locations: \(records)")
            completion(error: nil, records: records)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered this on your original question @caleb. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe instead of:

```
loadLocation((error, self.locArray))
```

You need to call this:

```
loadLocation() { (error, records) in
    // do something here with the returned data.
}
```